# JSObject in applet with JRE 1.7.0_21

Tags: java, javascript, applet, nullpointerexception

I've an applet, where I set the security manager to `null`.

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

And where I use `JSObject` to communicate with Javascript functions, through `eval` method

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this);
win.eval("jsfunct()");
```

Starting form JRE 1.7.0_21-b11, `eval` method return a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Any idea?

Comment: *"I've an applet, where I set the security manager to null."*  a) Why? ..but b) Don't do that.  Also, don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.  If your name is that important to you, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2054600/user2054600).

Comment: Oracle made significant changes in Applet security. I am having the same problem. My security manager is not set to null, my applet is signed with a valid certificate, it has scriptable="true" as well as mayscript="true". My manifest has "Trusted-Library: true" and "Trusted-Only: true". I use "call" method instead of "eval". It used to work before the upgrade and now it doesn't. Let me know if you find the answer.

Comment: Strange thing, it still works in the IE but not in Firefox. Could be a bug in FF.

Comment: It also works in Chrome. Must be a bug in the latest FF.